# How do I get SwiftUI to work with Core Data (after starting a project)?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I get this error when trying to get Xcode working with Core Data. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6000008a8820>
```

After commenting out all the other environments so that the persistence envinronment is only used in the top level, I still have the same error.

Here is the Apps Top-Level Swift File:

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

```
@main
struct Draw_DailyApp: App {
    
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

@FetchRequest(entity: Drawing.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Drawing.img, ascending: true)])



var orders: FetchedResults<Drawing>

@State var showOrderSheet = false


// Creating a global environment and placing it into the environment
@ObservedObject var searchObjectController: SearchObjectController = SearchObjectController()


var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
            .environmentObject(self.searchObjectController)
    }
    .onChange(of: scenePhase) { _ in
        persistenceController.save()
    }
}
```

}

and here is the file where persistent controller is used (Core Data xcdatamodeld has one Binary Data attribute called img)

Persistence.Swift

```
    import CoreData
import UIKit

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
    func save() {
        let context = container.viewContext

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Show some error here
            }
        }
    }

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Drawing(context: viewContext)
            newItem.img = Data()
            newItem.date = "02081999"
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DrawDaily")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                /*
                Typical reasons for an error here include:
                * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                * The device is out of space.
                * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

PS: I didn't start this project with Core Data, I added it in later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@FetchRequest` doesn't have a `NSManagedObjectContext` upon init. You are creating it with this line

```
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
```

Your `@FetchRequest` has to move down into the `ContentView` for it to work.

This line has to be called

```
 .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
```

when initializing the `View` that contains the `@FetchRequest`